# Custom UIView Background image

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm using `Swift` for my project. Created a custom `UIView` class like the following:

```
class AppBgView: UIView {

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        //self.isMemberOfClass(<#aClass: AnyClass#>)
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zeroRect)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "BGround.png")!)
    }
}
```

trying to set background image inside required `init()` method. But the background image doesn't seems to change. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try move it to override init (frame : CGRect)

Comment: tried. But no luck..

Comment: remove the word **convenience**, defiantly move `self.backgroundColor` to override `init()`

Comment: removed convenience. But xcode forcing me to insert convenience..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I manage to solve it. replaced the `self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "BGround.png")!)` code with this one:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "bground.png") {
    self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image).CGColor
}
```

The background image was added to the layer of that view. It works. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint in each one of this methods and see which one of the constructors is being called.
You will need to move the line

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "BGround.png")!)
```

To the constructor that being called.

In Swift A class must have at least one designated initializer. 
You may need to remove the word **convenience** from init().

Give this one a shot:
UIColor(patternImage:UIImage(named: "BGround.png")!).CGColor

Comment: Debugged it. required init() is called where I put the code.

Comment: Does it find the image?
If you define the variable before the backgroundColor does it return a UIImage or nil?

Comment: the view I'm subclassing is the main view in the viewcontroller

Comment: I've edited the answer. please take a look at the possible solution I've suggested. I think it might be the ! that slipped away

Comment: I tried with a solid color .redColor. It works. but the image doesn't work.  I didn't put ! sign. swift forced me to. Without this sign xcode gives following error.- "value of optional type UIImage? not unwrapped".

Comment: I changed the code like this:  if let image = UIImage(named: "bground.png") {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
        } & debugged it. It seems to enter the if condition. that means the image is correct. But no luck

Comment: Then Try UIColor(patternImage:UIImage(named: "BGriund.png")!).CGColor

Comment: it gives the error "cannot assign a value of type CGColor! to a value of tyoe UIColor?"

Comment: took a hint from your answer & modified it. Then it works. See my answer. Thanks a lot for ur patience.

Comment: amazing, glad it helped. Do you mind confirm my answer then? or up-vote it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 5

```
 self.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
 self.layer.contents = UIImage(named:"bground.png")?.cgImage
 self.bringSubviewToFront(self)
 self.clipsToBounds = true
```